# Блокирование кнопки в форме

Tags: javascript, html, html5, form, razor

нужно сделать так, чтоб кнопка `Save` блокировалась, если `UserName` пустой. Но не понимаю как это сделать)

```
<script>
        function agreeForm(f)
        {
            if (f.UserName = "")
                f.Save.disabled = "1"
        }
</script>
<form asp-controller="Calculator" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ErrorCode)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Computer name:</th>
            <th>User Name:</th>
            <th>Expression:</th>
            <th>Result:</th>
            <th>Error:</th>
            <th>Date:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ComputerName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Expression)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Result)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" disabled="0" onchange="agreeForm(this.form)"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Razor генерирует **статическую** разметку. Динамическое поведение необходимо делать вручную, на JS.

В обработчике вы присваеваете (`=`) вместо сравнения (`===`) и лишь пытаетесь блокировать кнопку, но никогда ее не разблокируете (`...disabled = false`)

Кроме того, у вас достаточно примитивное правило валидации, здесь можно обойтись возможностями HTML5 - с аттрибутом `required`, вообще без JS, [например](https://jsfiddle.net/03e1ywhj/):

```
<form>
  <label for="choose" required>Would you prefer a banana or cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Кнопка submit просто не нажмется, пока не удовлетворены все [валидационные правила](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

ЗЫ Проверку необходимо обязательно продублировать на сервере.